# Seeking information on Noble Hutchinson Fleming of Cork, Ireland

Tags: 19th-century, england, ireland, london

Noble Hutchinson Fleming was born in Cork in 1827 and later emigrated to London. I would like to know more about the family.

Comment: Anne-Isabelle - this is far too broad of a question to answer here. What information *specifically* do you want to know more about?

Comment: I think this question is too open-ended which is why someone marked it down - if you make it more precise then you might get more responses. For instance, the Limerick and Clare Examiner (22 September 1852) notes that Noble Hutchinson Fleming Esq married Emily Howe daughter of  late Revd. John Howe at the Wesley Chapel, George Street [Limerick].  I have no idea if this is useful to you, or if you already knew that. Maybe you could say a bit more about what you are looking for - as a starting point is there a particular individual you want to find out more about, and what sources have you used?

Comment: @rhm I agree with you and HarryVervet that this question is far too broad. Having already done some work to write your comment, I think you should copy/paste some content from it into an answer before the question is closed so that it may attract some upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

There is some information available online about Noble Hutchinson Fleming.

The Limerick and Clare Examiner (22 September 1852) notes that Noble Hutchinson Fleming Esq married Emily Howe daughter of late Revd. John Howe at the Wesley Chapel, George Street [Limerick].

This is confirmed by looking at the Civil Registration Marriage Index (via findmypast.ie) which provides the following reference:

- First name(s)    Noble Hutchinson
- Last name    Fleming
- Registration year 1852
- Registered Quarter/Year  1852
- Registration district    Limerick
- Volume 6, Page 644

There are lots of different avenues you could pursue e.g Methodist records, the Howe family, the 'Hutchinson' middle name which could well come from his mother's maiden name.  If there is an aspect you are particularly interested in, please get back and hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Noble Hutchinson Fleming moved to London and founded Silber & Fleming with Albert Marcius Silber. A lot more is known about his business partner than about him. I am considering the idea of writing a book about Silber & Fleming as I am convinced that the story of this highly successful enterprise is symbolic of the important changes happening during the 19th century, socially and economically. If I could make contact with either Fleming or Howe family members it would help answer questions about his background, why he moved to London, how the project came about, etc.